# Win32 unicode swprintf_s call generates buffer overrun warning

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I'm writing a small application to target Win32 using C++. The compiler is set to support unicode and I'm compiling in x64 mode. I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Everytime I call `swprintf_s`, like below:

```cpp
wchar_t buff[500] = { 0 };
swprintf_s(buff, sizeof(buff), L"Could not free DLL handle: 0x%X\n", GetLastError());
OutputDebugString(buff);
```

...I receive the following [C6386 compiler warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6386?view=msvc-160):

`C6386: Buffer overrun while writing to 'buff': the writable size is '1000' bytes, but '2000' bytes might be written.`

As an experiment, if I doubled the size of the buffer...

```cpp
wchar_t buff[1000] = { 0 };
swprintf_s(buff, sizeof(buff), L"Could not free DLL handle: 0x%X\n", GetLastError());
OutputDebugString(buff);
```

...the ranges within the warning simply shift up in accordance:

`C6386: Buffer overrun while writing to 'buff': the writable size is '2000' bytes, but '4000' bytes might be written.`

I'm wondering if someone might be able to help me understand why the above code (when explicitly passing the size of the buffer) generates a buffer overrun warning and, how I might go about fixing this.

Comment: `sizeof` returns the number of bytes, `swprintf_s` needs the number of chars. `sizeof(wchar_t) != 1`, you probably want `sizeof(buff)/sizeof(wchar_t)`.

Comment: Thanks, I find the documentation confusing as it states: `int swprintf_s(wchar_t *buffer, size_t sizeOfBuffer, const wchar_t *format, ...);` (Second parameter named sizeOfBuffer)

Comment: @JonMatthews the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sprintf-s-sprintf-s-l-swprintf-s-swprintf-s-l?view=msvc-160) states: "*sizeOfBuffer
Maximum number of **characters** to store.*"

Comment: Since this question is tagged [tag:c++], why aren't you using the C++-only function template instead? No need to specify the length in elements, meaning there's no opportunity to pass the wrong value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by van dench, the second parameter is the number of chars, not the size of the buffer in bytes.

Correct code:

```
wchar_t buff[500] = { 0 };
swprintf_s(buff, 500, L"Could not free DLL handle: 0x%X\n", GetLastError());
OutputDebugString(buff);
```